# WebApi and Ampersands in name

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, routes

So my angular website has a webapi with the following method.

```
[Route("items/{itemName}")]
public object GetMcguffinsByItem(string itemName)
{
    return _mcguffinsService.GetAllByItemName(itemName);
}
```

However, an item name can have an ampersand as a valid character. However when attempting to use items that do have an ampersand, the method will return a 400 badrequest.

Im not sure how to go about fixing this problem.

For more verification: I was under the impression that encoding and using %26 is all required to pass an ampersand to part of the URI. It seems to be a common answer when searching my problem. I have excluded the angular as I can verify that it builds the string correctly, and other names produce the desired result.

The javascript method encodeURIComponent() followed by using the angular service double encodes the item name, and returns a 404.

EDIT: 
Sample Input:
A&B 266
After Encoding:
A%26B%20266

Console:
angular.js:10722 GET http://localhost:60894/api/v1/mcguffins/items/A%26B%20266  404 (Not Found)

Using the browser on api directly with same input gives this error:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +11944671
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +55
```

Comment: URI encode all characters in the name before making the request?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am doing that, the result uses %26, as expected. Anything else i need to check?

Comment: Then please give a [mcve] to actually illustrate the issue.